# Multidimensional arrays, remove the duplicated array in next array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

My arrays result is like this one

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => Bank Transfer
            [ec] => 1000
            [accounts] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Account WD
                            [value] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Keterangan
                            [value] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => Wired
            [ec] => 1001
            [accounts] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Account WD
                            [value] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Keterangan
                            [value] => 
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Account ID
                            [value] => 
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

It's weird because 2nd array of **accounts** contains same value as first array.

```
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Account WD
                            [value] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Keterangan
                            [value] => 
                        )
```

How to prevent this duplicated so the 2nd array of **accounts** will only show

```
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Account ID
                            [value] => 
                        )
```

Here's my code

```
    $arr = $arr_pay = array();
      foreach($site_payment as $key => $value){
        if($value['status'] && $value['ec']>=1000){
          $payment_data_cust = unserialize(crypts($value['auto_wd_data'],'d'));
          foreach ($payment_data_cust as $ke => $va) {
            $arr[] = array("name"=>$va,"value"=>'');
          }
            $spc[] = array(
              "id"=>$value['id'],
              "ec"=>$value['ec'],
              "accounts"=>$arr
            );
        }
      }
```

Array of **$site_payment** contains

```
[Bank Transfer] => Array
    (
        [id] => Bank Transfer
        [ec] => 1000
        [status] => 1
        [auto_wd_data] => IjZRcWp1aGtzNmZHbjVPZTlkeStGZVNPaWdPY0lrZ0UyQnd6eFhxQUZoR1VEeU82TzVJZkdMelJrZzJKS3lxXC9yTm5meFBndFRlUDQ9Ig==
    )
[Dana] => Array
    (
        [id] => Wired
        [ec] => 1001
        [status] => 1
        [auto_wd_data] => IkNDek9IY1BtelVEeFFxZEtMc0hvalBkbVBRdENEZEJWakZoaFBJWkNBUk09Ig==
    )
```

I want to show the **auto_wd_data** of **$site_payments** with different array so it's became the result, but not duplicating in each array
Please help me to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplication is due to the $arr is not being reset

```
$arr_pay = array();
      foreach($site_payment as $key => $value){
        $arr = array(); // Resetting
        if($value['status'] && $value['ec']>=1000){
          $payment_data_cust = unserialize(crypts($value['auto_wd_data'],'d'));
          foreach ($payment_data_cust as $ke => $va) {
            $arr[] = array("name"=>$va,"value"=>'');
          }
            $spc[] = array(
              "id"=>$value['id'],
              "ec"=>$value['ec'],
              "accounts"=>$arr
            );
        }
      }
```